# Selecting first row in a table on loading in SWT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

How to select first row in a table after loading SWT table with data on startup.

1) Currently loading with some static data in a table. Would like to select first row by default during loading itself.

2) How to refresh the page when there is change in table row selection from default row.

Comment: Please edit your question and limit it to one specific problem. It looks like you have two distinct questions that you're asking here.

Comment: How to refresh the page when there is change in table row selection from default row.

Comment: Are you using `Table` or `TableViewer`?

Comment: I am using Table.

Answer (score 2):

For Jface `TableViewer`, use `Tableviewer.setSelection()` method.

For SWT `Table`:

```java
table.setSelection(index);
table.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event()); // to notify the page to update
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally found a solution. I have a custom row selecting with coloring and I didn't realize all I had to do, was to simply dispatch an event and not try selecting row manually.